# Traversing a directory tree

Tags: emacs, elisp

i am trying to traverse a given directory and create a list of files ending in .jpg.

```
(setq files (list ))

(defun jpg-list(directory)  
  (dolist (node (directory-files directory t ) )
      (if (file-directory-p node)      
          (if (not 
           (string= (substring node (- (string-width node) 1)) "."))
             (jpg-list node))
    (if (string-match ".jpg" node)
        (setq files (cons node files)))))
  files)
```

i would like to do this without using an external variable (files). What is the idiomatic way of doing this in elisp?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's my functional solution:

```
(defun jpg-list (dir)
  (if (file-directory-p dir)
      (append
       (directory-files dir t ".jpg$")
       (apply 'append (mapcar 'jpg-list (directory-files dir t "[^.]+"))))))
```

Answer (score 5):

Your best bet is use [`'directory-files`](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Contents-of-Directories.html#Contents-of-Directories) full interface and just use:

```
(directory-files directory t ".jpg$")
```

The bigger question was how to avoid the top-level variable, which is usually solved by a `'let` statement, e.g.

```
(defun jpg-list (directory)
  (let ((files))
    ...do something with files...
    files))
```

Comment: thanks, that solved my problem. But for different situation what is the idiomatic way of writing this kind of loop? using setq all over the place doesn't seem functional code?

Comment: if you want a more 'functional' approach you probably want to mapcar over your (directory-files) with a lambda where it recursively calls your function on subdirs.

Comment: Right, mapcar is more functional, but doesn't solve his problem.  You would need routines in '`cl` like `'remove-if`, `'remove`, etc.  It all depends on what you're doing.  The idiomatic way is to use `'directory-files` to its full extent.  The next way (with minimal code change) is to use a local variable via '`let', you can write a recursive routine, use `'cl` functions, etc. etc. etc.  Note: Emacs isn't functional, it's full of all sorts of side-effects...

Comment: nice, did not know about this function.